# No provider for NgbModalStack

Tags: ng-bootstrap

For some reason, I am suddenly getting this error out of the blue, with no code changes. Any ideas what would be causing this?

I was able to solve this with adding `NgbModule.forRoot()` to my imports,
but now I get this error:

> Property 'forRoot' does not exist on type 'typeof NgbModule'.

the application is running fine otherwise.

Comment: could you please post some sample code?

Comment: `NgbModule.forRoot()` is the method you should use from alpha.7, see: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes. Regarding the "Property 'forRoot' does not exist on type 'typeof NgbModule'." - is it IDE that is reporting it? Your question is not clear here...

Answer (score 30):

I've got the same problem with you.
I tried to add .forRoot() to NgbModule.
Try to configure your @NgModule decorator like this:

```
   imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ]
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 15):

adding  this one on my modules.ts works!

```
  imports: [
NgbModule.forRoot()
]
```

Comment: Property 'forRoot' does not exist on type 'typeof NgbModule'

Answer (score 1):

**For Angular 8**, Make sure you have added  NgbModule in app.module.ts
imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
HttpModule,
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
NgbModule     // .forRoot() is deprecated in Angular 8
]

And Downgrading "ng-bootstrap" to 5.x.x worked for me. I found the Angular ng-bootstrap compatibility here.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap